# How to (un)escape strings in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, string, escaping

Given a **counted** string (either an array of characters, or a wrapper like `std::string`), is there a "proper" way to escape and/or unescape it in C or C++, such that "special" characters (like the null character) become C-style-escaped and "normal" characters stay the way they are?

Or do I have to do it by hand?

Comment: So you're looking for some sort of STL function that converts `"\n"` into `"\\n"` runtime?

Comment: @muntoo: Yup, exactly (and vice-versa). It could be C though -- it doesn't *have* to be a part of STL (C++).

Comment: Do you want the sequence: `0` `65` `66` `67` to appear as the text `"\0ABC"`?

Comment: Do you want it to convert the characters into something C would understand or just add backslashes before special characters?

Comment: @Marlon: Yes, I'm looking for C-style escapes.

Comment: @icktoofay: I'm looking for C-style escapes, not just an extra backslash.

Comment: What is your goal here?  Are you dynamically generating C code?

Comment: @Adam: The goal is to display any arbitrary string in a known, human-readable form, and I've concluded that C-style escapes are best.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Will it also preserve the original formatting? i.e. Will it be something like [formatting marks in Microsoft word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/show-or-hide-formatting-marks-HA010102250.aspx)? If you converted all the newlines to `\n` and returns to `\r`, etc. then it'll all be one big long continuous mess if you tried rendering it in a console.

Comment: @In silico: It will be displayed in a list view control, so however the control displays the text, that's how it'll render. I will need newlines to be escaped (just like in C), but other than that, I'm not going to go out of my way to do anything special with accents or whatnot -- I just want it to be displayed (more or less) the same way as it would be in C source code, which would probably mean that anything funky (like accents and whatnot) should be displayed in the `\uABCD` format. (But again, I don't want to impose extra rules myself.  It should be the same way as in C.)

Comment: Objective-C has a function sort of like this -- [NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) (and it's inverse).  (% escapes rather than \ ones.)  One would think that a similar function exists in some C++ libraries, though I've never run across one.  Note that you need to know the character set being used (which code points are valid) if the function includes converting from UTF16 to Ascii.

Comment: (Likely similar functions exist in the networking facilities of other libraries.  Eg, there is similar functionality in QUrl in Qt, though it's not clearly exposed.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a function to process a single character:

```
/*
** Does not generate hex character constants.
** Always generates triple-digit octal constants.
** Always generates escapes in preference to octal.
** Escape question mark to ensure no trigraphs are generated by repetitive use.
** Handling of 0x80..0xFF is locale-dependent (might be octal, might be literal).
*/

void chr_cstrlit(unsigned char u, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    if (buflen < 2)
        *buffer = '\0';
    else if (isprint(u) && u != '\'' && u != '\"' && u != '\\' && u != '\?')
        sprintf(buffer, "%c", u);
    else if (buflen < 3)
        *buffer = '\0';
    else
    {
        switch (u)
        {
        case '\a':  strcpy(buffer, "\\a"); break;
        case '\b':  strcpy(buffer, "\\b"); break;
        case '\f':  strcpy(buffer, "\\f"); break;
        case '\n':  strcpy(buffer, "\\n"); break;
        case '\r':  strcpy(buffer, "\\r"); break;
        case '\t':  strcpy(buffer, "\\t"); break;
        case '\v':  strcpy(buffer, "\\v"); break;
        case '\\':  strcpy(buffer, "\\\\"); break;
        case '\'':  strcpy(buffer, "\\'"); break;
        case '\"':  strcpy(buffer, "\\\""); break;
        case '\?':  strcpy(buffer, "\\\?"); break;
        default:
            if (buflen < 5)
                *buffer = '\0';
            else
                sprintf(buffer, "\\%03o", u);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code to handle a null-terminated string (using the function above):

```
void str_cstrlit(const char *str, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    unsigned char u;
    size_t len;

    while ((u = (unsigned char)*str++) != '\0')
    {
        chr_cstrlit(u, buffer, buflen);
        if ((len = strlen(buffer)) == 0)
            return;
        buffer += len;
        buflen -= len;
    }
    *buffer = '\0';
}
```

Comment: I could've implemented it myself as well, but I was hoping that there would be a standardized solution of some sort. But I guess there isn't... +1 thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm sure you could; I'm sure I'm not the only person who has.  I've not come across a 'standard' solution.  I wrote the code I showed in September 2001 and last updated it in March 2007.  It was merely copy'n'paste, omitting the test code and version control information.

Comment: `str_cstrlit` doesn't work on zero length strings, the buffer will have no zero terminator. I edited the code, but the peer review failed, for whatever reason. Just make sure to write `buffer[0] = '\0'` over the while loop.

Comment: @lama12345: Hmmmm…yes, you're right.  It needs to be beefed up with some assertions, too (`str != 0 && buffer != 0 && buflen != 0`, for example).  In the original context where I wrote the code, zero length strings were never a possibility, so the extra checking wasn't necessary.  But as a general solution, it needs some tweaking.  The `void` return was also OK in context — the inputs wouldn't cause trouble.  Writing general purpose library code is hard.

Comment: The question asks about (un)escaping strings. This answer only seems to handle escaping strings.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than allocating a new buffer to contain the escaped string I like to escape my string while I write it to a stream.

The following function makes for readable and concise code.

```
struct Escaped
{
    const char* str;

    friend inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Escaped& e)
    {
        for (const char* char_p = e.str; *char_p != '\0'; char_p++)
        {
            switch (*char_p)
            {
                case '\a':  os << "\\a"; break;
                case '\b':  os << "\\b"; break;
                case '\f':  os << "\\f"; break;
                case '\n':  os << "\\n"; break;
                case '\r':  os << "\\r"; break;
                case '\t':  os << "\\t"; break;
                case '\v':  os << "\\v"; break;
                case '\\':  os << "\\\\"; break;
                case '\'':  os << "\\'"; break;
                case '\"':  os << "\\\""; break;
                case '\?':  os << "\\\?"; break;
                default: os << *char_p;
            }
        }
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Escaped{ "foo\n\tbar" } << std::endl;
}
```

Produces

```
foo\n   bar
```

Comment: @Mehrat, you've said in a comment that "The goal is to display any arbitrary string in a known, human-readable form". My code accomplishes that goal, right? I have read the question; be more constructive with your feedback.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit: it's literally **bolded** in the question.

Comment: @Mehrdad: If your complete rejection of this answer and of Tim's reading skills is based on the fact that the example takes `const char*` rather than `std::string` then that seems a little petty. You can trivially alter the loop preamble. The whole point of Tim's answer is that it doesn't matter whether the input is "counted" or not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit: no, that's far from the only issue. If you read the question or my comments on the accepted answer at all you realize I was not asking anyone for an implementation, and I quite explicitly said I could write one by hand if it wasn't built-in. Yet this answer shows outright ignorance of pretty much everything I wrote, hence my comment. Take it as you will.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Hope you wake up less grouchy tomorrow!!

Comment: The term "counted string" doesn't seem to be standard with a measly 2k hits on google. My answer works on an array of characters.

Comment: @Mehrdad your question asks for the proper way to do it, that sounds to me like you are asking for an implementation. Moreover I shouldn't have to read your comments to understand the question.

Comment: @TimKuipers: You were reading my comments? I [said the opposite](/questions/7369344/how-to-unescape-strings-in-c-c/49500603?noredirect=1#comment8904571_7369771) of "I'm looking for an implementation".

Answer (score 0):

```
//convert '\n' literal to escape code for '\n'
#define STRING "hello\\\\\nworld\\n"
char *p = malloc(strlen(STRING) + 1);
strcpy(p,STRING);
char *s = p;
char c;
for(;*p;++p)
{
  while(*p == '\\')
    {
      ++p;
      switch(*p){
      case '\\':
    c = '\\';
    goto gstat;
      case 'n':
    c = '\n';
      default:
    {
    gstat:
      strcpy(p-1,p);
      *(p-1) = c;
    }       
    break;
      }
    }
}
printf("%s",s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `C++` solution for unescaping a string for all the Googlers who come here:

```
std::string unescape_string(const std::string& input)
{
    std::string output;
    output.reserve(input.size()); // Reserve space to avoid frequent re-allocations

    for (size_t input_index = 0; input_index < input.length(); input_index++)
    {
        if (input[input_index] == '\\' && input_index + 1 < input.length()) // Check for escape character and ensure it's not at the end
        {
            switch (input[input_index + 1]) {
                case 'n': // Replace \n with newline
                    output += '\n';
                    input_index++;
                    break;

                case 't': // Replace \t with tab
                    output += '\t';
                    input_index++;
                    break;

                case '\\': // Replace double backslash
                    output += '\\';
                    input_index++;
                    break;

                case '"': // Replace \" with "
                    output += '"';
                    input_index++;
                    break;

                default:
                    output += input[input_index];
                    break; // In case of an unknown escape sequence, keep the original
            }
        }
        else
        {
            output += input[input_index]; // Copy the character as is
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

If someone has a complete, performant and robust solution using some library like `Boost`, feel free to share that as well.