# Converting escape sequence in C

Tags: c, regex, linux, unix

I have a char array called ArrayA from some user input that may contain escape sequence characters in it. I want to copy ArrayA into ArrayB character by character. With that said how would i then represent the escape characters from ArrayA into ArrayB? Simply copying the characters won't actually convert \t to a tab if i were to print ArrayB correct? It would just place \t as a character instead correct? Can i just input 0x09 into ArrayB for the \t escape sequence so that it will actually print a tab at that specific place in the array when printing ArrayB?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369344/how-to-unescape-strings-in-c-c

Comment: I saw that but i'm a little confused as i thought it was required to use hex byte to convert escape sequence back into a tab(\t in this case)

Comment: If it's an escape in `ArrayA` such as `'\t'` then it is also already a `0x09`, a tab. So you just copy it right on over. That is, I assume that `ArrayA` is a single `'\t'` which is an alias for `0x09`, and not two characters `'\'` and `'t'`.

Comment: So if a user inputs \\t it would be the escape sequence \t that would get stored into my char array correct? In that case if i were to copy over the char array to another char array and print it out i would not need to do any weird conversions to get it to output a tab when printing this new char array?

Comment: Read one byte at a time. If it's not a backslash, copy it. Otherwise, see what the next byte is. If that's a `t`, emit a `'\t'`, otherwise abort with error.

Comment: hmm but i thought escape sequence were one byte by themselves, are they two? For example in an array i thought it was represented as [\t] and not [\\][t]

Comment: An escape sequence is a sequence of (multiple) `char`s that represent another hard-to-type `char`.  For example, the sequence we call "`\t`" is the character `'\\'` then the character `'t'`, and commonly represents the ASCII control character `0x9 == '\t'`.

Comment: But I can't say whether your "ArrayA" contains control characters or escape sequences.

Comment: Okay, i have a few more questions.
1. does \0 at the end of a char array/string get stored as two characters as well or 1 character? Also when should you have to add a \0 at the end of a char array? If you copy char for char from ArrayA to ArrayB the \0 will be included in it correct? And if like i said it would only require a size of array+1 to get to the \0 because \0 is only 1 byte/char?
2. If you pass characters to ArrayB without including the \0 you would have to add it manually?
3. Instead of emitting a '\t' can we emit a 0x9 inside that char array position as an equivalent?

Comment: Oh and does 0x9=1 char in this situation if we can indeed input it into the array char instead of emitting a '\t'?

Comment: My reading of this question is that the input contains the character sequence "\\t" and the output should contain "\t" (a tab character).  The proposed duplicate is handling the reverse conversion,

Answer (score 3):

#### Function `cstrlit_chr()`

How about this:

```
/* Convert C Character Literal in (str..end] (excluding surrounding quotes) */
/* to character, returning converted char or -1 if string is invalid. */

/* Convert string containing C character literal to character value */
/* Returns -1 if character literal is invalid, otherwise 0x00..0xFF */
/* Does not support extension \E for ESC \033. */
/* Does not support any extension for DEL \177. */
/* Does not support control-char notation ^A for CTRL-A \001. */
/* Accepts \z as valid z when z is not otherwise special. */
/* Accepts \038 as valid CTRL-C \003; next character starts with the 8. */
/* Accepts \x3Z as valid CTRL-C \003; next character starts with the Z. */
/* Treats invalid octal escape \8 or \9 as 8 or 9 */
int cstrlit_chr(const char *str, const char *end, char const ** const eptr)
{
    unsigned char u;
    int rv;

    if (str >= end)
        rv = -1;    /* String contains no data */
    else if ((u = *str++) != '\\')
        rv = u;
    else if (str == end)
        rv = -1;    /* Just a backslash - invalid */
    else if ((u = *str++) == 'x')
    {
        /**
        ** Hex character constant - \xHH or \xH, where H is a hex digit.
        ** Technically, can be \xHHH too, if CHAR_BIT > 8; this nicety
        ** is being studiously ignored.
        */
        int x1;
        int x2;
        if (str == end)
            rv = -1;
        else if ((x1 = basedigit(*str++, 16)) < 0)
        {
            rv = -1;        /* Invalid hex constant */
            str--;
        }
        else if (str == end)
            rv = x1;        /* Single digit hex constant */
        else if ((x2 = basedigit(*str++, 16)) < 0)
        {
            rv = x1;        /* Single-digit hex constant */
            str--;
        }
        else
            rv = (x1 << 4) | x2;    /* Double-digit hex constant */
    }
    else if (isdigit(u))
    {
        /**
        ** Octal character constant - \O or \OO or \OOO, where O is an
        ** octal digit.  Technically, the constant extends for an
        ** indefinite number of octal digits; this nicety is being
        ** studiously ignored.  Treat \8 as 8 and \9 as 9.
        */
        int o1;
        int o2;
        int o3;
        if ((o1 = basedigit(u, 8)) < 0)
            rv = u; /* Invalid octal constant (\8 or \9) */
        else if (str == end)
            rv = o1;    /* Single-digit octal constant */
        else if ((o2 = basedigit(*str++, 8)) < 0)
        {
            rv = o1;    /* Single-digit octal constant */
            str--;
        }
        else if (str == end)
            rv = (o1 << 3) | o2;    /* Double-digit octal constant */
        else if ((o3 = basedigit(*str++, 8)) < 0)
        {
            rv = (o1 << 3) | o2;    /* Double-digit octal constant */
            str--;
        }
        else if (o1 >= 4)
            rv = -1;                /* Out of range 0x00..0xFF (\000..\377) */
        else
            rv = (((o1 << 3) | o2) << 3) | o3;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Presumably \a, \b, \f, \n, \r, \t, \v, \', \", \? or \\ - or an error */
        switch (u)
        {
        case 'a':
            rv = '\a';
            break;
        case 'b':
            rv = '\b';
            break;
        case 'f':
            rv = '\f';
            break;
        case 'n':
            rv = '\n';
            break;
        case 'r':
            rv = '\r';
            break;
        case 't':
            rv = '\t';
            break;
        case 'v':
            rv = '\v';
            break;
        case '\"':
            rv = '\"';
            break;
        case '\'':
            rv = '\'';
            break;
        case '\?':
            rv = '\?';
            break;
        case '\\':
            rv = '\\';
            break;
        case '\0':  /* Malformed: solitary backslash followed by NUL */
            rv = -1;
            break;
        default:
            rv = u; /* Nominally invalid: \X but X not special; return X. */
            break;
        }
    }
    if (eptr != 0)
        *eptr = str;
    return(rv);
}
```

It handles C89 character sequences; it does not handle Unicode (universal) characters (`\uXXXX` or `\U00XXXXXX`).

#### Function `basedigit()`

```
/*
** Convert character to digit in given base,
** returning -1 for invalid bases and characters.
*/
int basedigit(char c, int base)
{
    int             i;

#if (('z' - 'a') != 25 || ('Z' - 'A') != 25)
#error Faulty Assumption
This code assumes the code set is ASCII, ISO 646, ISO 8859, or something similar.
#endif /* Alphabet test */
    if (base < 2 || base > 36)
        i = -1;
    else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        i = c - '0';
    else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        i = c - 'A' + 10;
    else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        i = c - 'a' + 10;
    else
        i = -1;
    return((i < base) ? i : -1);
}
```

#### Sample usage

```
/* Sample usage */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char  data[] = "ab\\xFF\\03\\7\\377\\t\\?\\'\\\\yz";
    const char *end    = data + strlen(data);
    const char *start  = data;
    const char *next;
    int   c;
    while ((c = cstrlit_chr(start, end, &next)) != -1)
    {
        char buffer[20];
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "[[%.*s]]", (int)(next-start), start);
        printf("%3d (0x%.2X) %-10s - [[%s]]\n",  c, c & 0xFF, buffer, next);
        start = next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the range scanned is identified by a pointer to the start character and the end is identified by a pointer to the character after the end of the range (in the example, the `'\0'` at the end of the string, but the function works on arbitrary data and does not require that it is null terminated.  The input string has backslashes doubled up in the source code so that the actual string contains single backslashes.

If `c == -1`, conversion failed.  Otherwise, `c` contains the character, and `end` is a pointer to where the conversion finished.

Comment: Minor bits:  Suggest `if (isdigit(u) && (u < '8')) ` instead of `if (isdigit(u))`.  C11 6.4.4.4 1 implies octal sequence limited to 3.  Para 7 says "Each octal or hexadecimal escape sequence is the longest sequence of characters that can constitute the escape sequence." so such sequences have additional limits.   Nice answer, but could use some guidance on `end` and `eptr`.

Comment: @chux: The code limits octal constants to 3 digits.  It treats the erroneous data `"\\8\\9"` as equivalent to `"89"`; it could be upgraded to treat them as errors.  In longer sequences, such as `"\\038"`, it interprets that as `"\03"` (Control-C) followed by 8.  Note that hex strings are not limited to 2 hex digits by the grammar. Your mileage may vary; it works sufficiently well for me.