# How to escape special characters in a char* string in C

Tags: c, string, escaping

I'm getting a string from fgets function. I want to clean that string into a new string so that the second has all special and potentially dangerous characters scaped, something similar to what you could do with addslashes() or mysql_real_escape_string() in PHP. As defined in the PHP Manual:

> *mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a.*

I do not intent to send this data to a mysql query nor do I have a current connection to any SQL server, just want it cleaned in a simple CLI C program running in a linux machine. This is gonna be used in a simple Static Analysis with [Splint](http://www.splint.org/). I have looked into several other questions here and haven't got it.

```
void clean_string(char * origin, char * destiny)
{ 
   //copies the origin to destiny scaping characters
}
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Standard C doesn't have such a function and I don't know of a POSIX function doing this. On which platforms is your code supposed to run?

Comment: Oh, and you've heard about `gets` being dangerous (and obsolescent since C89, and removed in C11)?

Comment: There are no "special and potentially dangerous" characters unless you (or something else) interprets them that way. Better define exactly what you want here.

Comment: @greg-hewgill I have edited the question to clarify this

Comment: @mafso I'll use fgets instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369344/how-to-unescape-strings-in-c-c?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still unclear why you think the string has "dangerous" chars, but if you want to escape some of them:

```
const char *str = "my dangerous";
const char *ooh = "aeoui\\";

char buf[BIG_ENOUGH];
size_t bp = 0;

for (size_t sp = 0; str[sp]; sp++) {
    if (strchr(ooh, str[sp])) buf[bp++] = '\\';
    buf[bp++] = str[sp];
}
buf[bp] = 0;
```

Comment: I cant quite understand your code: the idea is that *str is the string i want to scape? is oops the sample string of characters i wanna scape?
how can I scape for example both \\ and \n characters to \\\\ \\n?

Comment: str is original string, ooh contains "dangerous" characters (in example, these are aeoui and backslash). buf is null-terminated output. Set ooh to "\\\n" and it will escape backslashes and newlines. @Sajhu

Comment: Note that this will not convert "\n" to "\\n", so printed output will contain backslashes at ends of strings, but not be a single string as if it can be passed back to c compiler.

Comment: Your answer is very unclear to me. Please try to explain what it does and use descriptive variable names.

Comment: @TimKuipers: it goes through chars of *str* and prepends backslash before them, if they are found in *ooh* - dangerous charset. *sp* stands for string pointer and *bp* for buffer pointer. It's sort of string copy routine that inserts \ before each char that has to be escaped. I can't see much requirement to rename things since this scheme is idiomatic to C programmers - like vec, pr, Escaped &e, etc in your own answers. Cheers!

Comment: @user3125367 Perhaps I should have known these conventions, but to me this answer remains too short and there's too little explanation to be informative when you read it the first time. Try improving your answer with comments and an explanation of what you are doing. Also try using descriptive variable names, rather than `ooh`.

Comment: @TimKuipers: Since you're seeing this problem better, feel free to edit answer's body, so future searches could lead to most understandable version. Try using names that you think are good for unexperienced C programmers.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the string directly. Loop through each position of the character array and if you have a special character then just replace it with something else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char str[] = "Hello\tworld\n!";
  int i, len;

  len = strlen(str);

  printf("%s\n", str);

  for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    switch (str[i]) {
    case '\n':
      str[i] = '$';
      break;
    case '\t':
      str[i] = '$';
      break;
    }
  }

  printf("%s\n", str);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is the most inefficient way. You have to hard code every bad character in order to identify it. Is there any other idea you have?

Comment: You seem to be asking for an existing library function of some sort that handles this. I am not aware of, nor do I see in a simple internet search, any libraries which handle C character array (not really a 'string' in the OOP sense) sanitation. In absence of such a library function made publicly available on a site like Github, you need to handle special characters manually. That means manually hard-coding each character in one form or another. if you don't like my verbose approach, see the one below.

Comment: Hard-coding, so you mean that's the only solution. I want to escape ASCII and ANSI escape codes so I need to hard-code them? I can't think of any logic to do such escaping without hard-coding them that's why I came here on SO. Don't you have any idea how can I do that in minimum efforts or I better start hard-coding them right away?

Comment: I mean, someone always hard codes the solution. And, some languages you'll find libraries which handle those solutions and in other languages you won't. My opinion: I suspect there aren't any high-quality libraries that perform string sanitation in C  because it really doesn't make sense to be writing services that require sanitization in C. You'll find sanitization libraries in PHP, Node JS, GoLang, C#, Java, etc. for a reason. But, you could take the initiative to port one to C if you'd like.

Comment: I already made a sanitation program in C and it works perfectly fine for Unicode strings as well. Thanks for your opinion though. It's on my GitHub repo but it's private but soon I'll make it public as my project does not work yet :).