# C load text from file, print escape characters

Tags: c

I'm loading a text file from disk to my C app. Everything works well, but the text contains multiple escape characters, like \r\n and after loading the text i want to keep count of those characters and display accordingly.

At this moment if I'm using printf on the string, it shows me this:

Hello\nMan\n

Any quick way of doing this?

Comment: this is weird. provide your code, please

Comment: Show us the relevant parts of your code.(How you are reading and printing the contents of the file) and the content of the text file

Comment: So the file actually contains an escaped version of the string and you want, for example, the newlines to be real new-lines?

Comment: Post your code. What you need to do is read lines using `fgets`,print them using `printf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a standard function for this, but you can roll your own:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 *      Converts simple C-style escape sequences. Treats single-letter
 *      escapes (\t, \n etc.) only. Does not treat \0 and the octal and
 *      hexadecimal escapes (\033, \x, \u).
 *
 *      Overwrites the string and returns the length of the unescaped
 *      string.
 */
int unescape(char *str)
{
    static const char escape[256] = {
        ['a'] = '\a',        ['b'] = '\b',        ['f'] = '\f',
        ['n'] = '\n',        ['r'] = '\r',        ['t'] = '\t',
        ['v'] = '\v',        ['\\'] = '\\',       ['\''] = '\'',
        ['"'] = '\"',        ['?'] = '\?',
    };

    char *p = str;      /* Pointer to original string */
    char *q = str;      /* Pointer to new string; q <= p */

    while (*p) {
        int c = *(unsigned char*) p++;

        if (c == '\\') {
            c = *(unsigned char*) p++;
            if (c == '\0') break;
            if (escape[c]) c = escape[c];
        }

        *q++ = c;    
    }
    *q = '\0';

    return q - str;
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "\\\"Hello ->\\t\\\\Man\\\"\\n";

    printf("'%s'\n", str);
    unescape(str);
    printf("'%s'\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

This function unescapes the string in place. This is safe to do, because the unescaped string cannot be longer than the original string. (On the other hand, that might not be a good idea, because the same char buffer is used for the escaped and unescaped string and you have to remember which it holds.)

This function doesn't convert the numerical sequences for octal and hex notation. There are [more complete implementations](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/postfix/postfix-229/postfix/src/util/unescape.c) around, but they are usually part of some library and rely on other modules, usually for dynamic strings.

There are similar [functions for escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369344/how-to-unescape-strings-in-c-c) a string, of course.