# How to convert std::string to raw string?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, rawstring

I have this string:

```
std::string str = "t\tt\\";
```

Can I convert `str` to raw string so it will be equal not to `"t.  t \"` but to `"t\t\\"` (like I write `R"t\t\\"`)?

If I do not use an R-literal, my symbols like `\t` `\n` `\\` will be replaced with tab symbol, new line character, or `\`. I want to convert the string var in which these symbols are replaced to a raw string in which they are not replaced.

So, can I convert string with escaping to string without escaping?

Comment: I don't get the question.  `"t.  t \"` is `"t\t\\"`.  Can you show how you want to use the string, as it is very unclear to me what you actually want to do.

Comment: Hmm if you mean is there a string that wil output "t\t\\" in c++?
Then the code should be std::string str = "t\\t\\\\";  (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)

Comment: So, are you just trying to convert a `std::string` instance that already has tabs/newlines/other characters into their escape sequences? E.g. a string containing a tab should have it replaced with `\t`?

Comment: @Human-Compiler, exactly.

Comment: You can use a loop.

Comment: So you know the key word "unescape". Have you tried searching for "how to unescape a string in c++"? :) you could've had the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369344/how-to-unescape-strings-in-c-c) 45 minutes ago.

Comment: Note that the unescaping does not guarantee something that matches the original. `"\x41"` will unescape to `"A"` and `"??("` will unesape to `"["` (until C++14).

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
std::string str = "t\tt\\";
std::string::size_type pos = 0;

while ((pos = str.find_first_of("\t\n\\", pos)) != std::string::npos)
{
    switch (str[pos])
    { 
        case '\t':
            str.replace(pos, 1, "\\t");
            pos += 2;
            break;
        case '\n':
            str.replace(pos, 1, "\\n");
            pos += 2;
            break;
        case '\\':
            str.replace(pos, 1, "\\\\");
            pos += 2;
            break;
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/P76LeZ)